# Why does Visual Studio attempt to deploy to emulator when device is selected

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, deployment

**Problem**

I am running Visual Studio 2017 and attempting to deploy a Xamarin app to my Android hardware (Motorola Moto G 4) which is plugged in to my computer via USB. When I attempt to deploy to it in Visual Studio, I get the following output:

```
Starting deploy Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
C:\Users\vchelaru\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_x86 -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  Your CPU: 'AuthenticAMD'
Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86 cannot be started.
Xamarin.Android does not support deploying the previous version. Please ensure your solution builds before deploying it.
------ Deploy started: Project: VolumeTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Error: Cancelled
======== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
======== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Question**

Why is Visual Studio attempting to start or deploy to emulator when my hardware is selected?

**What I've tried**

The USB debugging is connected according to my Android device and I have authorized the device for debugging on the device. In fact, I've even been able to deploy to this device a few times, but now I can't do it anymore.

The Motorola Moto G 4 is selected in the dropdown next to the "play" button in Visual Studio. I've rebuilt the project, and have selected **Tools** -> **Android** -> **Restart ADB Device**. When restarting, the Motorola Moto G 4 device temporarily disappears, but then it's found again.

I've tried unplugging and plugging the hardware back in. I've attempted restarting Visual Studio. Whenever I do this, the hardware device is selected by default so I know Visual Studio sees it.

I've also tried restarting Windows.

Comment: Look forward for this one, as I have the same problem with my Huawei P8 Lite 2017 running Android 7.0. with my previous with 5.1 didn't happen.. I have to make sure that I select it every time, else, it will pick the emulator. I think it might have to do with the compile to version doesn't match with the installed one on the device.. not sure.. I also get issues when trying to deploy to device if the version does not match...
But in stuff like this, usually I use the Smiley/Frown face on the bottom right corner... usually someone says something

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this resolves the core issue (which maybe is a Visual Studio/Xamarin Bug) but I did find a workaround.

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Android** -> **Android Emulator Manager**
2. Make sure the **Android Virtual Devices** tab is selected
3. Select any device which is x86 and click the **Delete...** button.
4. Press the **Refresh** button to verify no x86 devices are still in the list
5. Close the window
6. Rebuild the project
7. Press the **play** button to deploy

This solved it for me. Removing all x86 devices somehow told Visual Studio to no longer attempt to deploy an x86 emulator, and I was able to run on device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an emulator, you need to install Intel HAXM before proceeding. And try not to use 64bit emulators as they may open but will not display anything. Also they are not good for performance.
[Here is the link for HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm)

If you are using a physical device, make sure you check the target of your application in Your_App -> Properties and select the proper API your mobile has.